# PHP xdebug not working for Visual Studio Code

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, xdebug

I have followed to the letter instructions for setting up xdebug with Visual Studio Code: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/nicktrog/2016/02/11/configuring-visual-studio-code-for-php-development/

So all config files, files, etc are installed and tested as working outside of PHP.

Currently I am running PHP using the built in server (`php -S localhost:8000 -t`).

This works fine and I can see output in my browser. Similarly within VS Code I can run my code fine by running <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + B</kbd>. It also works inside Eclipse after installing PDT plugin.

Using `phpinfo()` I can see that xdebug is there and working fine. However, when I 'listen for XDebug' (I have changed `launch.json` to use port `8000`) or press <kbd>F5</kbd> all that happens is my status bar turns orange, the debug pane shows nothing and the debug buttons show pause/stop and I have to click one of these to quit the program, i.e. it does nothing.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that if you running PHP using the built in server, you must configure the `php.ini` file of the CLI (in my case is `sudo nano /etc/php/5.6/cli/php.ini`), not of Apache 2.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't change launch.json to use port 8000, unless you've set xdebug.remote_port=8000 in your php.ini file. The port of the php server and xdebug are two different things. I guess that your xdebugremote_port is 9000 since using port 8000 for both things is impossible, so just change launch.json back to 9000.